# sending email works locally not on server

Tags: asp.net

Sending email works locally but when I upload my code to my server on bigrock it does not work. I get this error.

> Error Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.Smtp Permission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

My code:

```
mm.Subject = "Nomination Received";
mm.Body = str.ToString();
mm.IsBodyHtml = false;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "password");

smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Send(mm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Web.Config file has the trust level set to full

```
 <configuration>
  <system.web>
    .....
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

you must set the following in System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient variable (e.g. *smtp *):

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);
```

smtp.EnableSsl = false; // check if your ISP supports SSL

Comment: i have tried with the trust level but that does not work

Comment: where should i set System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient variable (e.g. *smtp *):

Comment: The place where you are initializing  SmtpClient object

Comment: i didn't get you can tell in detail

Comment: you must configure smtp server for sending mail for GoDaddy Email please visit https://it.godaddy.com/help/configurazione-email-con-nopcommerce-5620

Comment: You may need to contact your hosting provider about the smtp details that you need to use.They block port 25? Please ask them.

Comment: yea port 25 is blocked they told me i can try sending mail through script.. you have any idea how to do it